# Why i have stage.height/width is 0 using PixiJS?

Tags: pixi.js

In function setup the value of app.stage.height is 0. Why? There is a text for validator(zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz)

```
       let Application = PIXI.Application,
            Container = PIXI.Container,
            loader = PIXI.loader,
            resources = PIXI.loader.resources,
            TextureCache = PIXI.utils.TextureCache,
            Sprite = PIXI.Sprite,
            Rectangle = PIXI.Rectangle;

        let app = new Application({ 
            width: 512, 
            height: 512,                       
            antialias: true, 
            transparent: false, 
            resolution: 1
          }
        );

        document.body.appendChild(app.view);

        loader
          .add("/img/treasureHunter.json")
          .load(setup);

        function setup() {
          console.log(app.stage.height)

          let id = PIXI.loader.resources["/img/treasureHunter.json"].textures;
          let dungeon = new Sprite(id["dungeon.png"])
          let treasure = new Sprite(id["treasure.png"]);
          let explorer = new Sprite(id["explorer.png"]);
          explorer.y = app.stage.height / 2 - explorer.height / 2;
          console.log(app.stage.height)
          explorer.x = 68;


          app.stage.addChild(dungeon);
          app.stage.addChild(explorer);
          app.stage.addChild(treasure);
        }
```

Comment: Can you create working example in jsfiddle / codepen etc which will show this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stage is a Container, whose height is always calculated from its children. Until you don't add any children to the stage, its height will be zero.

Also, the stage's height is not equal to the canvas `renderer.view` height.